# how to make condition that if my GPS is not open

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gps, google-maps-api-2

how to make condition that if my GPS is not open, my app will open GPS option first then after opening my GPS, it will continue to search for my location. please help and thanks in advance for the answers.

here is my .java file

```
static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
 static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);

GoogleMap googlemap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());
    if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
        dialog.show();
    }
    else{
        SupportMapFragment mf = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        googlemap = mf.getMap();
        googlemap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Getting the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Getting Current Location
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if(location!=null){
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);

    }
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


    // Getting latitude of the current location
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();

    // Getting longitude of the current location
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    // Showing the current location in Google Map
    googlemap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    // Zoom in the Google Map

    googlemap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
    googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
    .title("Your Here!"));

       }


@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}









}
```

Answer (score 0):

I pushed this out to a methods as follows:

```
/**
 * Sets up the devices location services to report location and updates the lat and long of the device if available
 */
public void initialiseLocationServices() {
    // Initialise objects
    locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean gps_enabled = false;
    boolean network_enabled = false;
    boolean hasLocation;

    try {
        gps_enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {

    }

    try {
        network_enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {

    }

    //  I am only interested in at least one being on.
    // hasLocation = gps_enabled || network_enabled;
    //if(hasLocation) { my way of doing things

    // You want to do it like this:
    if(!gps_enabled) {
        Intent gpsOptionsIntent = new Intent(  
        android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);  
        startActivity(gpsOptionsIntent);
    } else {
        SupportMapFragment mf = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        googlemap = mf.getMap();
        googlemap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Getting the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Getting Current Location
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if(location!=null){
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
    }
```

Note: this is pseudo only, you will need to handle the change of GPS settings etc and I have not tested this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the location manager for this

```
private LocationManager locationManager;
public boolean isGPSEnabled;

locationManager = (LocationManager)mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

if(isGPSEnabled)
{
    if(locationManager != null)
    {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

Comment: if you're trying to access GPS when your app starts then you can put this in your onCreate() method :)

Comment: i insert it below protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

why it has errors in the lines 

private LocationManager locationManager;
public boolean isGPSEnabled;
locationManager = (LocationManager)mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

it says illegal modifier.

Comment: do not put the private LocationManager and public boolean inside the onCreate() method, declare them as global variable

Comment: can you send another code for that, including my code and your code? please? thanks in advance